# OpenCV: Optical Flow calculation in a pipe with Gunnar Farneback

Tags: python, opencv, opticalflow, optics-algorithm

I would like to calculate the optical flow in a endoscopy video of a pipe. I would use the cv2 Farneback Optical FLow to calculate the optical flow. With the optical flow i would like to calculate the movement of the endoscope (forwards or backwards). My Video Frame looks like this:
[image: The pipe endoscope videp]
My results looks like this, the picture of optical flow is always black, any idea why?
[image: Results optical flow]

```
import cv2
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def select_video_file():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Video auswählen", filetypes=[("Video Dateien", "*.mp4 *.avi *.mov *.mkv *.wmv *.flv *.mpeg")])
    return file_path

def horn_schunck(frame1, frame2):
    # Def Optical flow
    I1 = cv2.cvtColor(frame1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY).astype(np.float32) / 255.
    I2 = cv2.cvtColor(frame2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY).astype(np.float32) / 255.

    # Optical flow calculated with Gunner Farneback
    #flow = cv2.calcOpticalFlowFarneback(I1, I2, None, 0.5, 3, 15, 3, 5, 1.2, 0)
    flow = cv2.calcOpticalFlowFarneback(I1, I2, None, 0.5, 3, 15, 3, 5, 1.2, 0)

    return flow

def main():
    global flow
    # Choose file
    video_path = select_video_file()   

    # Check file
    if not video_path:
        print("Kein Video ausgewählt.")
        return

    # Video import
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)

    # Cideo check
    if not cap.isOpened():
        print("Fehler beim Öffnen des Videos.")
        return

    ret, frame1 = cap.read()
    if not ret:
        print("Fehler beim Lesen des ersten Frames.")
        return

    # Frame size
    height, width, _ = frame1.shape
  

    while True:
        ret, frame2 = cap.read()

        if not ret:
            break

        # Optical flow is now calculated between two frames
        flow = horn_schunck(frame1, frame2)
        
        #draw optical flow in colors
        
        global hsv
        global rgb
         
        hsv=np.zeros_like(frame1)
        hsv[...,1]=255
         
        mag, ang =     (flow[...,0], flow[...,1])
         
        hsv[...,0]=ang*180/np.pi/2
        hsv[...,2]=cv2.normalize(mag,None,0,255,cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
        rgb=cv2.cvtColor(hsv, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)
         
        plt.subplot(3,1,1)
        plt.imshow(frame1),plt.title('frame1'),plt.xticks([]),plt.yticks([])
        plt.subplot(3,1,2)
        plt.imshow(frame2),plt.title('frame2'),plt.xticks([]),plt.yticks([])
        plt.subplot(3,1,3)
        plt.imshow(rgb),plt.title('optical flow'),plt.xticks([]),plt.yticks([])
        plt.show()
        

        
        frame1 = frame2

    # Video-Stream release
    cap.release()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```